# Android studio with TheMovieDB.com API wrapper : unable to start activity ComponentInfo and lots of other errors

Tags: javascript, java, android, api, themoviedb-api

I am using Android Studio 2.0(preview).
In order to display some info about certain movies , I downloaded [Themoviedb.com API Wrapper by holgerbrandl](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/themoviedbapi/)
, added a dependency but just after I add two lines of the wrapper-related code I get a lot of errors I'm not familiar how to deal with.

```
TmdbMovies movies = new TmdbApi("myAPIkey_here").getMovies();
MovieDb movie = movies.getMovie(5353, "en");
```

I'm a very inexperienced newbie - thus the need of your help :)

If any details needed, please remind me to add them.

Here's my logcat :

```html
11-29 02:35:26.710 5736-5736/com.example.michael.movienight W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
11-29 02:35:26.710 5736-5736/com.example.michael.movienight W/System.err: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
11-29 02:35:26.710 5736-5736/com.example.michael.movienight W/System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
11-29 02:35:26.720 5736-5736/com.example.michael.movienight D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-29 02:35:26.720 5736-5736/com.example.michael.movienight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.michael.movienight, PID: 5736
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.michael.movienight/com.example.michael.movienight.MainActivity}: info.movito.themoviedbapi.tools.MovieDbException: Failed to read configuration
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                               Caused by: info.movito.themoviedbapi.tools.MovieDbException: Failed to read configuration
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.<init>(TmdbApi.java:48)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.<init>(TmdbApi.java:35)
                                                                                  at com.example.michael.movienight.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                               Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:150)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderFields(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:210)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getHeaderFields(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:178)
                                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderFields(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.tools.WebBrowser.readHeader(WebBrowser.java:226)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.tools.WebBrowser.request(WebBrowser.java:143)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.tools.WebBrowser.request(WebBrowser.java:112)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.requestWebPage(TmdbApi.java:64)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.AbstractTmdbApi.mapJsonResult(AbstractTmdbApi.java:58)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.AbstractTmdbApi.mapJsonResult(AbstractTmdbApi.java:45)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.AbstractTmdbApi.mapJsonResult(AbstractTmdbApi.java:40)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbConfig.getConfig(TmdbConfig.java:18)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.<init>(TmdbApi.java:44)
                                                                                  at info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi.<init>(TmdbApi.java:35) 
                                                                                  at com.example.michael.movienight.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

(full MainActivity.java below)

```js
package com.example.michael.movienight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbApi;
import info.movito.themoviedbapi.TmdbMovies;
import info.movito.themoviedbapi.model.MovieDb;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 
    TextView MainText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        MainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);
        TmdbMovies movies = new TmdbApi("my_API_key_here").getMovies();
        MovieDb movie = movies.getMovie(5353, "en");



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually learning TheMovieDB API for a school project right now.

Apparently, whenever you want to use the network on android and connect to something, you need to put the statement inside an async task; something to do with network connections not working on the main thread.

To do this you can create a custom AsyncTask in your activity like so:

```
protected class MovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MovieDB> {

    protected MovieDB doInBackground(Void... v) {
        TmdbMovies movies = new TmdbApi("myAPIkey_here").getMovies();
        MovieDb movie = movies.getMovie(5353, "en");
        return movie;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MovieDB movie) {
        // Do something with movie
    }
}
```

And your MainActivity onCreate would look like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    MainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);

    MovieTask mt = new MovieTask();
    mt.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It, indeed, solved the crash problem. But my last and probably easy for you question is : how do i store those values> (I mean returns into my MainActivity?
Or where can i read the info on the particular topic?

Comment: I'm still really new to android development as well so I don't know the standard. I've just been moving everything into onPostExecute, because I know for sure everything is connected/loaded before I try to do anything.-